# Anticipated Preload of JS & CSS via AJAX - how much is too much?

Tags: jquery, caching, optimization, pagespeed

I'm interested to hear from some others devs out there how much you take advantage of "[anticipated preloading](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#preload)"?

We have a couple of decent sized, minified sets of JS and CSS files (around 50k each, set up with all the cache bells and whistles on our cdn) on our homepage but then a 123kb minified/cacheable/cdn'd set of JS files and a bit more CSS on the page that the user is inevitably going to go to right after our homepage.

So I've been toying with the preloading by using jQuery's getScript() (with the cache option set) and have been loading the 123kb file on pageload on the mainpage to make the user's transition into the richer area of the site a bit quicker and more pleasant.

Things seem to perform great on my computer but a) that's not everyones setup and b) something just feels a bit funny seeing so much weight in KB (~550kb) on my Firebug Net Console. Granted when I return it's 565kb/568kb cached and only about 2.6s onload..but still..

Thoughts? Words of wisdom? Does this have a big impact on mobile users?

Curious to hear your thoughts, Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I don't think it matters what others have found, you should measure it for yourself - otherwise, you'll always be flying blind. For all you know, your extra javascript could be hurting your actual homepage performance. The key observation to keep in mind is that every site is different: different demographics, breakdown of browsers, mobile vs. desktop, and most importantly, business KPI's.

All of that to say: measure it, don't rely on anecdotes. There are good tools out there that can help you. If you run Google Analytics, take a look at custom variables. You can tag a visitor across a session or until a cookie expires and take a conditional path based on that cookie. Eg, some users get the preload path, others don't. Once you have this in place, compare the data in GA against your KPI's: ad click rates, bounce rates, pages per visit, purchases, funnel rates, etc.

Alternatively, GA also recently launched "Content experiments" which allows you to run tests (including site optimization) right from within GA, and with all the statistical machinery to analyze your results.

Last but not least, GA is not the only game in town. Search for "a/b testing" and you'll find plenty of 3rd party tools, as well as open-source plugins you can drop into your own framework.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Good call on the A/B test and tracking users' progression. I've done A/B tests and also the MultiVariate ones but just hadn't really thought about doing it for this. Cheers @igrigorik